WebGL Faces of a Pyramid Using Different Images Texture-Mapping - Cannot see images - Need Example to Better Understand
I am hoping someone can support reviewing my attached html and js code to correct my error. Or at minimum share with me a similar example so that I can learn to correct my errors.
The expectation is to create a textured Pyramid successfully using different images in .js (WebGL) on a each face of a pyramid. Please see my html and js code. I am unable to see any image. I tried fixing the CORS error with local host and still see nothing. I do not know where the error is to correct the issue.
HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<button id = "ButtonX">Rotate X</button>
<button id = "ButtonY">Rotate Y</button>
<button id = "ButtonZ">Rotate Z</button>
<button id = "ButtonT">Toggle Rotation</button>

<img id="face0" src="face0.png" hidden crossorigin="anonymous"></img>
<img id="face1" src="face1.jpg" hidden crossorigin="anonymous"></img>
<img id="face2" src="face2.png" hidden crossorigin="anonymous"></img>
<img id="face3" src="face3.png" hidden crossorigin="anonymous"></img>
<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
#version 300 es

in vec4 aPosition;
in vec4 aColor;
in vec2 aTexCoord;

out vec4 vColor;
out vec2 vTexCoord;

uniform vec3 uTheta;

void main()
{
    // Compute the sines and cosines of theta for each of
    //   the three axes in one computation.
    vec3 angles = radians(uTheta);
    vec3 c = cos(angles);
    vec3 s = sin(angles);

    // Remeber: thse matrices are column-major
    mat4 rx = mat4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0, c.x, s.x, 0.0,
            0.0, -s.x, c.x, 0.0,
            0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    mat4 ry = mat4(c.y, 0.0, -s.y, 0.0,
            0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            s.y, 0.0, c.y, 0.0,
            0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);


    mat4 rz = mat4(c.z, s.z, 0.0, 0.0,
            -s.z, c.z, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    vColor = aColor;
    vTexCoord = aTexCoord;
    gl_Position = rz * ry * rx * aPosition;
    gl_Position.z = -gl_Position.z;
}
</script>

<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
#version 300 es

precision mediump float;

in vec4 vColor;
in vec2 vTexCoord;
out vec4 fColor;

uniform sampler2D uTex0;
uniform sampler2D uTex1;

void
main()
{
    fColor = vColor*(texture(uTex0, vTexCoord)*texture(uTex1, vTexCoord));

}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../SmithLarisaProj7/initShaders.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../SmithLarisaProj7/utility.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../SmithLarisaProj7/MVnew.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../SmithLarisaProj7/SmithLarisaPyramid.js"></script>



<body>
<canvas id="gl-canvas" width="1024" height="1024">
Oops ... your browser doesn't support the HTML5 canvas element
</canvas>
</body>
</html>



JS:



"use strict";

var canvas;
var gl;

var numPositions  = 12;

var positionsArray = [];
var normalsArray = [];
var colorsArray = [];

var texSize = 64;

var numChecks = 8;

var axis=0;

var program;

var texture;

var imageUrls = [
    "face0.png",
    "face1.jpg",
    "face2.png",
    "face3.png"
];

var t1, t2;

var c;

var flag = true;


var vertices = [
   vec4(0.5, -0.2722, 0.2886, 1.0),
   vec4(0.0, -0.2772, -0.5773, 1.0),
   vec4(-0.5, -0.2722, 0.2886, 1.0),
   vec4(0.0, 0.5443, 0.0, 1.0)
];
var vertexColors = [
    vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0),  // blue
    vec4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0),  // magenta
    vec4(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0),  // cyan
    vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0) // white
 ];
 

/* var image1 = new Uint8Array(4*texSize*texSize);

    for ( var i = 0; i < texSize; i++ ) {
        for ( var j = 0; j <texSize; j++ ) {
            var patchx = Math.floor(i/(texSize/numChecks));
            var patchy = Math.floor(j/(texSize/numChecks));
            if(patchx%2 ^ patchy%2) c = 255;
            else c = 0;
            //c = 255*(((i & 0x8) == 0) ^ ((j & 0x8)  == 0))
            image1[4*i*texSize+4*j] = c;
            image1[4*i*texSize+4*j+1] = c;
            image1[4*i*texSize+4*j+2] = c;
            image1[4*i*texSize+4*j+3] = 255;
        }
    }

var image2 = new Uint8Array(4*texSize*texSize);

    // Create a checkerboard pattern
    for (var i = 0; i < texSize; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j <texSize; j++) {
            image2[4*i*texSize+4*j] = 127+127*Math.sin(0.1*i*j);
            image2[4*i*texSize+4*j+1] = 127+127*Math.sin(0.1*i*j);
            image2[4*i*texSize+4*j+2] = 127+127*Math.sin(0.1*i*j);
            image2[4*i*texSize+4*j+3] = 255;
           }
    }
*/
var positionsArray = [];
var colorsArray = [];
var texCoordsArray = [];

var texCoord0 = [
    vec2(0, 0),
    vec2(0, 1),
    vec2(1, 1),
    vec2(1, 0)
];
var texCoord1 = [
    vec2(0, 0),
    vec2(0, 1),
    vec2(1, 1),
    vec2(1, 0)
];
var texCoord2 = [
    vec2(0, 0),
    vec2(0, 1),
    vec2(1, 1),
    vec2(1, 0)
];

var texCoord3 = [
    vec2(0, 0),
    vec2(0, 1),
    vec2(1, 1),
    vec2(1, 0)
];

var xAxis = 0;
var yAxis = 1;
var zAxis = 2;
var axis = xAxis;

var theta = vec3(45.0, 45.0, 45.0);

var thetaLoc;

function configureTexture(images, textureUnit) {
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0 = textureUnit);
    texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, images);
    gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                      gl.NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(program, "uTexMap" + textureUnit),textureUnit);
    }

function tri(a, b, c, texCoord) {
     positionsArray.push(vertices[a]);
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[0]);

     positionsArray.push(vertices[b]);
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[1]);

     positionsArray.push(vertices[c]);
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[2]);

     positionsArray.push(vertices[a]);
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[0]);

     positionsArray.push(vertices[c]);
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[2]);

}

function colorPyramid()
{
    tri(1, 2, 3, texCoord0);
    tri(2, 3, 0, texCoord1);
    tri(3, 1, 2, texCoord2);
    tri(0, 2, 1, texCoord3);
}

window.onload = function init() {

    canvas = document.getElementById("gl-canvas");

    gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2');
    if (!gl) alert("WebGL 2.0 isn't available");

    gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    gl.clearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    var numImages = imageUrls.length;
    for(var i=0; i<numImages; i++) {
        var images = document.getElementById("face" + (i+1));
        configureTexture(images, i);
    }

    //
    //  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers
    //
    program = initShaders(gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader");
    gl.useProgram(program);

    colorPyramid();

    var cBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(colorsArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    var colorLoc = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "aColor");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(colorLoc, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(colorLoc);

    var vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(positionsArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    var positionLoc = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "aPosition");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLoc, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLoc );

    var tBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, tBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(texCoordsArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    var texCoordLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "aTexCoord");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(texCoordLoc, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(texCoordLoc);

    var image = document.getElementById("face");
    configureTexture(image);

    
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation( program, "uTex0"), 0);

    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE3 );
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture3);
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation( program, "uTex1"), 3);


    thetaLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "uTheta");


 document.getElementById("ButtonX").onclick = function(){axis = xAxis;};
 document.getElementById("ButtonY").onclick = function(){axis = yAxis;};
 document.getElementById("ButtonZ").onclick = function(){axis = zAxis;};
 document.getElementById("ButtonT").onclick = function(){flag = !flag;};

    render();
}

var render = function() {
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    if(flag) theta[axis] += 2.0;
    gl.uniform3fv(thetaLoc, theta);
    for(i=0;i<12;i++){
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture[i+start])
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 12*i, numPositions);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}


I tried using a php opening a local host to fix CORS error, but still am unable to see any image. Therefore, I believe there is an issue in the code.

Try Using_textures_in_WebGL from MDN
